# "Entry point 'Trainers.FastTreeRegressor' not found" in Microsoft.ML

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, ml.net

I'm trying to build an ML model using a FastTreeRegressor in Microsoft.ML, laregly copying code from the [Taxi Fare Prediction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/tutorials/taxi-fare) tutorial into my preexisting environment, where I can swap out the data and some parameters. It all builds successfully, but running yields the error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Entry point 'Trainers.FastTreeRegressor' not found'

How can I fix this?

---

*Side note:* I've excluded code samples because the tutorial includes them, and knowing the answer ahead of time (see below), they wouldn't add to the solve-ability of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the error, it seemed pretty similar to an improperly formatted EXE. That led me to noticing I had not added a reference to Microsoft.ML to my EXE project, only a class library.

Adding the Nuget Package to my Console project introduced a compile-time error that I had to build for x64 (compared to Any CPU), but doing both of those things resolved the issue.

Worth noting: the error does occur when the configuration is x64 and the Nuget package has not been added; *both* steps need to be performed.

---

Looking at the logs from Nuget, I also see:

> Generating MSBuild file *[project file]*.csproj.nuget.g.props.
>   Generating MSBuild file *[project file]*.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
>   Writing lock file to disk. Path: *[project directory]*\obj\project.assets.json

Which do seem to confirm the package is a bit more deep-rooted than some, explaining the requirement. Not surprising.

Comment: Had the same issue, thought it was tied to this: https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/issues/618 but could not get past it. Your suggestion worked for me. Thank you.